# "... matching query does not exist." error, but object clearly does exist

Tags: python, django

I have a `lesson` model:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name
```

A `sound` model:

```
class Sound(models.Model):
    sound_hash = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    lessons = models.ManyToManyField(Lesson, verbose_name="associated lessons", related_name="words")
```

And a `test_pair` model:

```
class TestPair(models.Model):
    master_sound = models.ForeignKey(Sound, related_name="used_as_master")
    user_sound = models.ForeignKey(Sound, related_name="used_as_user")
```

My form looks something like this:

```
class SoundTestPairForm(ModelForm):
    user_sounds = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Sound.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = TestPair
        fields = ['master_sound']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SoundTestPairForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['master_sound'] = forms.CharField()
        self.fields['master_sound'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = 'readonly'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SoundTestPairForm, self).clean()
        if 'user_sounds' not in cleaned_data.keys():
            raise forms.ValidationError('You must select at least one sound to be compared')
        cleaned_data['master_sound'] = Sound.objects.get(pk=self.fields['master_sound'])
        return cleaned_data
```

This is throwing a `DoesNotExist` error. The traceback points to this line: `cleaned_data['master_sound'] = Sound.objects.get(pk=self.fields['master_sound'])`

The local vars are as follows:

```
self    

<SoundTestPairForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(master_sound;associated_test;associated_lesson;user_sounds)>

cleaned_data    

{'associated_lesson': u'pooooooooooooooooooooooop',
 'associated_test': u'cats a',
 'master_sound': u'ad27ec5e0d048ddbb17d0cef0c7b9d4406a2c33',
 'user_sounds': [<Sound: Pants>]}
```

But when I go to `python manage.py shell`, and import my model: 
`Sound.objects.get(pk=u'ad27ec5e0d048ddbb17d0cef0c7b9d4406a2c33')
<Sound: oombah>`

It hits the appropriate object.

This is something I've been dealing with for a long time, and it's super frustrating. I try to switch my logic around and ultimately it ends up throwing a `DoesNotExist` error, regardless of what I try.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want `master_sound` to be changed, why not just remove it from the form? Then you won't have to make the field readonly or set it in `cleaned_data`.

Comment: @Alasdair I want it to be displayed (so the user knows which master sound they're associating to a user sound).

Comment: You don't need a field to display the value. For example you could do `{{ form.instance.master_sound }}` in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should replace:

```
Sound.objects.get(pk=self.fields['master_sound'])
```

with:

```
Sound.objects.get(pk=cleaned_data['master_sound'])
```

When the **Form** is valid, `cleaned_data` will include a key and value for all its fields and you can see that in your question as well (The local vars paragraph).

In general speaking you should do validation in the individual `clean_<fieldname>` methods. So:

```
def clean_master_sound(self):
    master_sound_key = self.cleaned_data.get('master_sound')
    try:
        master_sound=Sound.objects.get(pk=master_sound_key)
    except Sound.DoesNotExist:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Sound with id: %s does not exist", master_sound_key)
    return master_sound
```

Comment: Dude. I hate you so much. Thank you.

Comment: You can't necessarily trust `cleaned_data`. The user can remove the `readonly` attribute using their browser tools and submit a different value. However, if you [disable the field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) with `self.fields['master_sound'].disabled = True` in the `__init__` method, then Django will ignore the value from the user and it is safe to use the value from `cleaned_data` for that field.

Comment: @Alasdair This doesn't work in Django 1.8, I believe

Comment: The `disabled` argument was added in Django 1.9. Django 1.8 is now end of life and doesn't receive security updates, so I wouldn't write about it unless the question specifies it.

Comment: @Alasdair Ah, yes. My mistake—I was using 1.8 because that's what Xubuntu installed from apt, but I've upgraded to 1.11. That being said, fields when disabled don't send through their information in a POST. In my case, I think readonly is still the easiest (I'm not too concerned about security; this is all in-house).

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's not sent in the POST request, because Django will add the initial value to the cleaned data for you.